# How to achieve strong consistency in hazelcast map across multiple clusters

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Currently hazelcast is setup in 3 clusters with each clusters having 3 members and wan replication is used to sync the clusters. I have multiple maps in hazelcast. It worked fine for all the maps but for one of the map, i want to achieve strong consistency across all the clusters in real time so that update in that particular map should get reflected immediately in another cluster as well.How can i achieve this in hazelcast?

Answer (score 1):

WAN Replication is an enterprise feature and since you are using it, you are entitled to commercial Hazelcast support. I strongly advise that you take this up with them.

As for strong consistency across WAN replicated clusters, the only thing that you can do to achieve instant replication is to reduce the wan queue size to 1. Other than that, it is neither wise to attempt nor possible to have strong consistency across systems that are geographically different and are connected via WAN link - think of network latencies.